# How to get the html tags of the selected text in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am searching for JS code that will show me the tag name of the selected text.

Basically, if I have selected the `dolor` text, and that text is surrounded by html tags, like so: `<strong>dolor</strong>`, the JS code should show me `strong`.

Example text:

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor</strong> sit amet</p>
```

Example code so far:

```js
var selectedTextRange = userSelection.getRangeAt(0);
const parentElement = selectedTextRange.commonAncestorContainer;

// `parentElement.tagName` display the `P` tag, and not the strong tag.
// How do I get the `strong` tag?
if (parentElement.tagName === 'strong') {

  console.log("parentElement.tagName === 'strong'");
  parentElement.replaceWith(parentElement.innerHTML);

} else {

  const strongElement = document.createElement("strong");
  selectedTextRange.surroundContents(strongElement);

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's a single string that surrounded by a single pair of html tags and does not contain any other tags, you can do it with regex. Anything more involved - you need a real parser.

Comment: Maybe you need to put the focus on Node instead of Element (despite Element is also a Node object). When you have, for example a <p> tag, it is considered an element, but inside that element, every piece of string is a Node.

Comment: @PM77-1 I am afraid I have basic JS knowledge, if there is some example code where I could work on, it woud be much appreciated. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @rafaelmi Any example code which I can play with?

Comment: Updated my Q with more content

Comment: `.tagName.toLowerCase()` --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName